# trying to reuse a function to append stuff into the DOM, appendChild not working as spected

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

So i have this function:

```
export function Home() {
 const moduleContainer = document.createElement("div");
 const uiContainer = document.querySelector("#ui-container");
 uiContainer.innerHTML = "";
 moduleContainer.id = "module-container";
 moduleContainer.classList.add("module-container", "min-height");
 const removeStats = statsUI(gameState.player, uiContainer);
 const removeInv = inventory(gameState.player, uiContainer);
 const battleBossButton = createButton("Boss", "Batalla", ()=>{
    Battle(bossMonsters.squeletonKing, "Pradera");
 });
 const battleButton = createButton("Mob", "Batalla", ()=>{
    Battle(monsters.goblin, "Montaña");
 });
 const shopButton = createButton("Shop", "Tienda", ()=>{
    Shop();
 });
 moduleContainer.appendChild(battleButton);
 moduleContainer.appendChild(battleBossButton);
 moduleContainer.appendChild(shopButton);
 mainContainer.appendChild(moduleContainer);
}
```

The first time i run this function everything works fine but when i (using a different function) empty the mainContainer and rerun this function the moduleContainer doesn't get appended again, the thing is that if i console.log the moduleContainer it does have the buttons inside of it, but the mainContianer doesen't have anything inside, i'm not sure what is going on, any ideas?

To clarify what i mean i took this screenshot
[image]

as you can see the first time it runs the dom looks correct
the second time main container has nothing inside.

EDIT: Main container is defined in a constants file and exported like this `export const mainContainer = document.querySelector("#main-container");`
Also createButton function comes from a helper file and looks like this

```
export function createButton(text, id, callback) {
 const button = document.createElement("button");
 button.id = id;
 button.classList.add("btn", "btn-custom");
 button.innerText = text;
 button.addEventListener("click", () => callback());
 return button;
}
```

Comment: where is `mainContainer` defined? Is it still pointing  to the correct element?

Comment: I guess it all depends on how the codeo `createButton()` is done ?

Comment: umm i will edit the original post with this info sorry!

Comment: What does `const uiContainer = document.querySelector("#ui-container");
 uiContainer.innerHTML = ""` do, where in your dom is that? Looks like a bad idea.

Comment: your buttons are created with identical IDs, it's not very good...

Comment: try to use `let button = document.createElement("button");` instead of const...?

Comment: and better do `button.addEventListener("click", callback);`

Comment: Oh yeah i know a lot is wrong there but im just trying stuff out, those buttons wont go there, i just want to know why this isnt rendering the second time, but yeah i will make sure ids arent identicall and also make all functions a callback for the btns. I'll try the let instead of const idea, i'll let you know if it works! :)

Comment: no it doesnt work changing const to let

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with any given `id`.

Comment: **Again**: You ***MUST*** make sure your document does ***never*** have duplicate `id`s.